# Modelagem de dados via JPA e Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Estou fazendo um projeto com JPA referente a um sistema de cotação e estou com dúvidas em como montar o relacionamento entre as classes, e gostaria (se possível) de algumas opiniões.

Meu projeto é um sistema de cotação, onde a empresa irá criar uma cotação e irá selecionar quais parceiros e setores irão fazer parte. A princípio criei as seguintes entidades:

- Cotacao: irá conter o cabeçalho da cotação;
- Parceiro: irá conter o cadastro de todos os parceiros;
- Setor: irá conter o cadastro dos setores;
- Itens: irá conter o cadastro dos itens que estão atrelados aos setores;
- ItensLancados: irá conter o lançamento de quantidades e valores digitados pelos parceiros.

A minha dúvida maior agora é em como montar o relacionamento entre elas. Tentei montar um relacionamento desta forma:

- `Cotacao` irá conter uma lista da entidade `Parceiro` com `@OneToMany` (uma cotação poderá ter um ou mais parceiros);
- `Cotacao` irá conter uma lista da entidade `Setor` com `@OneToMany` (uma cotação poderá ter um ou mais setores);
- `Setor` irá conter uma lista da entidade `Itens` com `@OneToMany` (um setor poderá ter um ou mais itens);
- `Parceiro` irá conter uma lista da entidade `ItensLancados` (um parceiro poderá ter um ou mais itens lançados).

Quando executo o projeto e vejo como o BD foi criado não consigo encontrar relação nas tabelas entre o item lançado com o item, nem entre o item lançado com a cotação que o parceiro digitou.

Alguém teria alguma dica de como poderia montar este relacionamento?

Seguem as classes para análise.

**Cotacao**:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_COTACAO", sequenceName = "SEQ_COTACAO", initialValue = 1)
public class Cotacao implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2871116154931914363L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_COTACAO")
    private Integer codCotacao;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataInicio;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataFim;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cotacao")
    private List<ItensLancados> itensLancados;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "cotacao_parceiro", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cotacao_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parceiro_id"))
    private List<Parceiro> parceiros;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "cotacao_setor", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cotacao_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "setor_id"))
    private List<Setor> setores;

}
```

**Setor**:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_SETOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_SETOR", initialValue = 1)
public class Setor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1651773345231721498L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_SETOR")
    private Integer codSetor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "setor")
    private List<Itens> itens;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "setores")
    private List<Cotacao> cotacoes;

}
```

**Itens**:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ITENS", sequenceName = "SEQ_ITENS", initialValue = 1)
public class Itens implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7243205344072660982L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ITENS")
    private Integer idItens;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "itens")
    private ItensLancados itensLancados;

    @ManyToOne
    private Setor setor;

}
```

**Parceiro**:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_PARCEIRO", sequenceName = "SEQ_PARCEIRO", initialValue = 1)
public class Parceiro implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3959545077780299993L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_PARCEIRO")
    private Integer codParceiro;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parceiro")
    private List<ItensLancados> itensLancados;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parceiros")
    private List<Cotacao> cotacoes;

}
```

**ItensLancados**:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CotacaoParceiroId.class)
public class ItensLancados implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9021268714143165841L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cotacao_id")
    private Cotacao cotacao;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    private Itens itens;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parceiro_id")
    private Parceiro parceiro;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

seu mapeamento pode estar errado ou sua modelagem está indo em um caminho caminho diferente do que vc diz que quer, seria importante vc postar o código do que fez para poder iedntificar em que vc pode ter se enganado

mas por hora vc pode seguir esse tutorial [Hibernate – One-to-Many example (Annotation)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) é simples e prático, e vc pode usar para comparar com o que vc já tem fez

Comment: Olá quikkoo, editei o enunciado com os códigos das classes e seus relacionamentos caso queira dar uma olhada. Obrigado pela atenção.